# Rails fire model callback when attribute updates to a new value or is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, activemodel

I’m trying to get a `before_update` model callback working where `quote_file_date` is automatically timestamped based off whether `quote_file` is created, updated or removed. The purpose of this is so that I can track when the file is created and updated.

I’m unsure how to implement ActiveModel::Dirty to get this working properly, but the expected behaviour should be:

1. When `quote_file` is created, a `quote_file_date` timestamp is created.
2. When `quote_file` value changes, the `quote_file_date` timestamp is updated.
3. If `quote_file` is removed, the `quote_file_date` is set back to nil.

Currently, I have:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :quote_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: quote_file.identifier.changed?

  private

  def quote_file_updated?
    self.quote_file_date = Time.now
  end

end
```

And the error I get back from this is:

```
undefined method `quote_file' for #<Class:0x007fa3bbedfec0>
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this using callbacks in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change the `before_update` callback to:

```
before_update :quote_file_updated?, on: [:create, :update], if: ->(r) { r.quote_file_changed? }
```